# Android Unable to access java files in library

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-camera, zxing

After a lot of struggle and research I am writing this for help. Being a new in to Android and Java literally spent few days. I am sure I am missing something silly but need insight.

I am using Android studio and have added Zxing QR scanner in to my project. Now I want to edit few methods in the library to do some customisation. I have added the library via Gradle. This is the library I have used https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner.

I have followed the basic instructions and added the library via gradle. Integration is successful. Now I want to customise the UI. So I got hold of the library here
[image: Zxingscanner path]

When I got hold of ViewFindView and tried to edit the method, I wan not able to edit it. Then I realised it is a class and also auto generated. I am supposed to edit the Java files.
[image: ViewFinderView.class]
The respective java file with all the code in the methods is here
[ViewFinderView.java](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/core/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/core/ViewFinderView.java)

1. How do I use it?
2. Is there a way to get hold of the java files respect to those class files.
3. How can I edit those files so that I can customise them?

I think all the above questions are kind of same. What do I do?
I am happy to provide more information.

Greatly appreciate your time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The library won't contain source-code. You'll need to import the source if you want to start customizing it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have added the library via Gradle.

That is your problem. In order to add the library to your project you have to import it as a module instead.

1. Download the repository (either via `git clone` or download as zip from Github)
2. Import project as a module in Android Studio (File -> Import Module or File -> New -> Import Module)
3. Edit source files

You will need to make your changes to the files in the imported module not the ones found in the build directory.

Comment: ahhh okay Great ... Thanks very much. I did as you said. Downloaded and imported it as module. Now I am getting a gradle sync error. Error:(12, 0) Could not find property 'supportLibraryDependency' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1b7c6573.

Comment: Which library did you import? You need to import Zxing and probably Core as well depending on what you want to change

Comment: Yup I imported both core and Zxing.

Comment: This time I added the core and Zxing individually and tried separately but no result. I removed both and everything is back to normal. That means is there some kind of dependency I am missing or some support library, while importing core and Zxing? When I go in to its manifest, for http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android it says, URI is not registered ?